Limit of Normalized Integral Involving $x f(x)$ for $f \in L^1(0, \infty)$
Let $f \in L^1(0, \infty)$, meaning $f$ is an integrable function on $(0, \infty)$. I am trying to prove that:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_0^n x f(x) \, dx = 0.
$$
What I used:

For any $\epsilon > 0$, since $f \in L^1(0, \infty)$, there exists $R > 0$ such that:
$$
   \int_R^\infty |f(x)| \, dx < \epsilon.
   $$

Splitting the integral as:
$$
   \frac{1}{n} \int_0^n x f(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{n} \int_0^R x f(x) \, dx + \frac{1}{n} \int_R^n x f(x) \, dx,
   $$
the first term should vanish as $n \to \infty$ since $\frac{R}{n} \to 0$. For the second term, I expect that the integrability of $f$ ensures it also tends to zero.


My Approach:

For the first term $\frac{1}{n} \int_0^R x f(x) \, dx$:

On $[0, R]$, $x \leq R$, so:
$$
 \left| \frac{1}{n} \int_0^R x f(x) \, dx \right| \leq \frac{R}{n} \int_0^R |f(x)| \, dx.
 $$
As $n \to \infty$, $\frac{R}{n} \to 0$ and $\int_0^R |f(x)| \, dx$ is finite. Hence, this term vanishes.


For the second term $\frac{1}{n} \int_R^n x f(x) \, dx$:

On $[R, n]$, $x \leq n$, so:
$$
 \left| \frac{1}{n} \int_R^n x f(x) \, dx \right| \leq \frac{1}{n} \cdot n \int_R^n |f(x)| \, dx = \int_R^n |f(x)| \, dx.
 $$
Since $\int_R^\infty |f(x)| \, dx < \epsilon$, the integral $\int_R^n |f(x)| \, dx$ is smaller than $\epsilon$ for $n > R$.


Combining these results:

For any $\epsilon > 0$, the total integral satisfies:
$$
 \left| \frac{1}{n} \int_0^n x f(x) \, dx \right| \leq \frac{R}{n} \int_0^R |f(x)| \, dx + \epsilon.
 $$
As $n \to \infty$, the first term vanishes, leaving:
$$
 \limsup_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{1}{n} \int_0^n x f(x) \, dx \right| \leq \epsilon.
 $$



Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, I conclude:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_0^n x f(x) \, dx = 0.
$$
My Question:
Is my decomposition and reasoning correct?
Thank you for your feedback and insights!

One line proof: DCT.

Thank you for the reply! Do you mean applying the Dominated Convergence Theorem (DCT) by observing that $ \frac{x}{n} f(x) \leq |f(x)| $,and since $ f \in L^1(0, \infty) $?
If so, how do we ensure that the pointwise limit of $ \frac{x}{n} f(x) $ as $ n \to \infty $ gives the desired result? Specifically, I  do not understand how we guarantee that $ \frac{x}{n} f(x) \to 0 $ pointwise, and how do we rigorously conclude that the integral of this also goes to $ 0 $? Could you clarify this step?
Thanks again for your insight!

Read the statement of DCT. You have written a  complete proof in the comment, but still thinking that it is not rigorous.

I think this is a correct proof. Of course, DCT is proved along the same lines.
